# CakePHP 3.0 and new project

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm starting the development of a new personal website/blog and I chose CakePHP as framework.
But I have a question : the actual version is 2.7 but the new major one 3.0 is already in beta. What should I do ? 
Do I directly start develop with 3.0 and a potential deployment of website with the beta version of the framework or do I still use the "old" 2.7 version with a code not compatible with 3.0 ?
Thank you.

Comment: You are asking for opinions. please see how to ask a proper question http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: just wait a short time. they gonna release the release candidate soon i guess. until then you can start coding with the beta locally and wait for the release to deploy it on a live system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working a lot with Cakephp 2, and i'm currently learning Cakephp 3. What I can say so far is:

- cakephp 3 introduces a lot a interesting new functionnalities (i won't detail here, you can find many resources on internet for that).
- cakephp 3 is really a major release: many things have changed. Even if I know very well cakephp 2, i really have difficulties to learn how to use cakephp 3. Lot of stuff to re-learn.
- you can see their roadmap here => https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/wiki/3.0-Roadmap . They are not so far from a stable release (i would say 3 to 4 months from now).

So If I were you, and if you do not plan on prod before a few months, or if you plan on using cakephp for a personal website, I would definitely start using cakephp 3.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that question depends solely upon the degree of risk that you can tolerate. Deploying an application running Beta software is risky. There may be undiscovered bugs or other issues that will impact the functionality or security your project. If you need to ensure stability, I recommend the current build. Otherwise, enjoy the beta. Keep in mind that the new features that come with 3.0 may or may not be important to you anyway.